# React: Flex-direction row not taking effect

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I know there are a thousand similar questions, but mine has almost no context, generic as can be, and right out of the box. Why is the flex-direction row property not taking effect?

### React View

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        <h1>The About us page.</h1>
        <Fragment className="container">
          <p>Dog</p>
          <p>Cat</p>
          <p>Other Dog</p>
        </Fragment>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

### CSS

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

The result is that those 3

tags are in a column. I would upload a picture but for some reason it won't work.Expected result is that "Cat", "Dog", and "Other dog" be in a row rather than 3 columns.

As far as I can tell form all the guides online this should be correct: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp

What is the problem?

Comment: did you write this code inside index.css??
did you import it correctly??

Comment: No, I wrote it in Styles.css and imported it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Fragment`  is a component, `className` goes to `props` object and does not pass as actual style.

Just wrap the items in a div and give it the class:

```
<Fragment>
  <h1>The About us page.</h1>
  <Fragment>
    <div className="container">
      <p>Dog</p>
      <p>Cat</p>
      <p>Other Dog</p>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Man I knew it had to be something like that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are using Fragment instead of div. React.Fragment is just a syntax sugar to allow to return multiple elements from component. After React.JS builds DOM, fragment becomes nothing, so you have no wrapper over your  elements.

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html